# Setting up a AWS cloudwatch alert when ElasticsearchRequests are too high

Tags: aws-cloudformation, amazon-cloudwatch

I am trying to setup a cloudwatch alert that if more than lets say 5000 http requests are sent to an AWS ES cluster using CloudFormation, I see there is the `ElasticsearchRequests` metric i can use and this is what i have so far:

```
  ClusterElasticsearchRequestsTooHighAlarm:
    Condition: HasAlertTopic
    Type: 'AWS::CloudWatch::Alarm'
    Properties:
      AlarmActions:
      - {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ParentAlertStack}-TopicARN'}
      AlarmDescription: 'ElasticsearchRequests are too high.'
      ComparisonOperator: GreaterThanThreshold
      Dimensions:
      - Name: ClientId
        Value: !Ref 'AWS::AccountId'
      - Name: DomainName
        Value: !Ref ElasticsearchDomain
      EvaluationPeriods: 1
      MetricName: 'ElasticsearchRequests'
      Namespace: 'AWS/ES'
      OKActions:
      - {'Fn::ImportValue': !Sub '${ParentAlertStack}-TopicARN'}
      Period: 60
      Statistic: Maximum
      Threshold: 5000
```

Does this look correct?

Should I use `SampleCount` instead of `Maximum` for the `Statistic`?

Any advice is much appreciated

Answer (score 1):

According to the AWS Doc about monitoring ELasticSearch/OpenSearch clusters, the relevant statistic for the metric ElasticsearchRequests is `Sum`.

Here is what the [docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticsearch-service/latest/developerguide/es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics.html#es-managedomains-cloudwatchmetrics-cluster-metrics) say:

### OpenSearchRequests

*The number of requests made to the Elasticsearch/OpenSearch cluster.*

**Relevant statistics: Sum**